# How to get info about Spring beans and their dependencies in a legacy application?

Tags: java, spring, reverse-engineering, legacy

Suppose I have a legacy `Spring` application, which includes a few jars and dozens of beans. Is it possible to get a full diagram of beans and the dependencies from the application binaries (jars) ?

Comment: By parsing XML configuration files?

Comment: Yes, but the application uses Spring annotations rather than XML files.

Comment: Even better and easier! Use reflection. Just seek for required annotations. Like `@Bean` .

Comment: You probably need to look for `@Awutowired`,`@Resource` also and  I am afraid it is not enough to get the full map of the dependencies. That's why I a looking for a `Spring` tool to do that.

Comment: IntelliJ Idea has a very good support for Spring, including the ability to generate a dependency diagram: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/spring-dependencies-diagram.html if you are not using it now, you can download the trial version to see if that fits your needs: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/

Comment: [STS](https://spring.io/tools) can generate every imaginable Spring-related diagram.